# How to use REGEDIT to adjust 'machine inactivity limit' in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm trying to setup my laptop, so that when I don't use mouse or keyboard for some number of seconds, the lock-screen will appear. (I'm on Windows-11)

I'd hoped to find a way to dig down (in the GUI) starting at
start->settings... but guessing my way down always results in
failure.  From google-searches, it seems that use of REGEDIT
is the ONLY way to do this (?!?)

My 79-year-old brain is no longer up to the task of deciding
to start with "REG QUERY HKLM..." or "REG QUERY HKCU..."
etc, etc.

Could someone please post the full-cmd needed to get to the
value of the needed key using REGEDIT?  (I DO know that I'll need to change it from its default-value of 0, to the number of seconds of inactivity wanted to trigger lock-screen.)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way, by clicking `Start` > `Run` > `gpedit.msc`

Now follow the tree down to `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`.

[image]

Find the policy setting, and edit it

[image]

Probably need a reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: The first part of the answer can shortened to : Run `gpedit.msc`.

Comment: I ran `gpedit` and got an error, but now you say that I know i forgot to add the `.msc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the registry entry via sysinternals procmon with filter "category = write".  There's no way to disable it in the group policy interface?  Looks like setting it to 0 disables it, or delete this registry entry InactivityTimeoutSecs value.

```
get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System `
  InactivityTimeoutSecs

InactivityTimeoutSecs : 999
PSPath                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio
                        n\Policies\System
PSParentPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio
                        n\Policies
PSChildName           : System
PSDrive               : HKLM
PSProvider            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```